# How many flight control shutoff valves are there in Boeing 737?

Tags: boeing-737, hydraulic-system

I came to know from a source that there are total 6 flight control SOV 3 of which associated with each of system A and B hydraulic system .but in 737 FCOM under stand by hydraulic section in schematic diagram they have shown only 2 in total, 1 associated to each hydraulic system .so I am little bit confused .

Comment: The FCOM only shows one per hydraulic system, but my guess is that there is actually three (on each for Rudder, Elevator and Elevator Feel Computer, Aileron).